Future Dates in Daily Visit Calendar
I've been using the Daily Visit Calendar to track my activity on Stack Overflow, and I noticed that it's possible to navigate to future dates. Since the primary purpose of the calendar is to track past and current activity, the ability to go to future dates seems unnecessary.


OK, granted going to the future isn't quite useful for that calendar widget. However, it's an extremely minor inconvenience. If you can even call it that. Honestly, I'd prefer to be able to see the future. Say, I open the calendar to see my activity and it's the end of the month, so I flip to the next month to check where a date falls. Because maybe on the 12th next month, I'll have to travel, so if I'm tracking my activity, I might want to make sure I log in on that day. Granted again - minor thing but don't see a very good reason to limit the calendar to only be up to current month.

Your point is valid. I just shared my thoughts but people are down voting this, is anything wrong with my opinion

@NIVESHD Voting is different on meta. For feature-requests, voting also indicates agreement and disagreement with the proposal itself.

Frankly, we do not even need to reach for the "voting is different on meta" mantra. Downvotes can express "I don't think this is useful", which is a valid opinion.

Can you explain why this is a problem?

Seems like something with return on investment approaching 0. TBH, until now, I wasn't even aware it exists... what's the point of it -- something to entertain those utterly bored?

Yeah, well..., be happy the Calendar ueberhaupt works now, it used to be broken and to display just an empty container with a spinning wheel for several months [Aug.2023-Jan.2024]. (See 'Error when clicking calendar view for daily visits', + several Duplicates...)

Although we understand your reasoning — looking into the future is likely not very useful in this case — the effort to block someone from navigating to the future isn't worth the potential value in our opinion. There may even be a use case for someone wanting to look into the future. We'll be keeping this functionality to accommodate those potential use cases and can assume that if users don't want to navigate to the future, they can choose not to do so.
